# How to authenticate to Project Online PSI services?

Tags: c#, office365, ms-project-server-2013

I have the MS Project Online account at sharepoint.com and I need to authenticate from client C# code to PSI services to get list of projects.

Server has Forms based authentication. I am trying to login via next code:

```
SvcLoginForms.LoginForms loginform = new SvcLoginForms.LoginForms();
loginform.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@myserver.onmicrosoft.com", "password");            
loginform.Url = "https://myserver.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx";
loginform.Login("admin@myserver.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
```

When I am executing loginform.Login I am getting SoapException with message: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: account". Inner exception xml is:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Value cannot be null.
```

Parameter name: account

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication to Project Online PSI services is described in this excellent article: http://www.umtsoftware.com/blog/how-to-project-online-psi/

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, secpassword);
```

instead of

```
new NetworkCredential("admin@myserver.onmicrosoft.com", "password");
```

### First: Install required Client SDK

- SharePoint Client SDK :
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=35585
- Project 2013 SDK:
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30435

### Second: add the reference to your project

1. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
3. Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll

You can find the dlls in `%programfiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI`
and `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Project 2013\REDIST`

## Here is sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

public class Program
{
    private const string pwaPath = "https://[yoursitehere].sharepoint.com/sites/pwa";
    private const string username ="[username]";
    private const string password = "[password]";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SecureString secpassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) secpassword.AppendChar(c);


        ProjectContext pc = new ProjectContext(pwaPath);
        pc.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, secpassword);

        //now you can query
        pc.Load(pc.Projects);
        pc.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach(var p in pc.Projects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }

        //Or Create a new project
        ProjectCreationInformation newProj = new ProjectCreationInformation() {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "[your project name]",
            Start = DateTime.Today.Date
        };        
        PublishedProject newPublishedProj = pc.Projects.Add(newProj);
        QueueJob qJob = pc.Projects.Update();

        JobState jobState = pc.WaitForQueue(qJob,/*timeout for wait*/ 10);

    }

}
```

Comment: While given code fragment works, it does not answer the original question. It explains how to connect through CSOM, while question was how to connect through PSI. For instance, I must connect and work exactly with PSI.